# ASP.Net: Svg images inside <img> tag.

Tags: asp.net, html, svg

I have an svg image that I want to display within the  tag, but somehow it is not rendered in any of the browsers. I even tried adding the following line to the web.config file.:

```
 <staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
</staticContent>
```

Still it doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the HTML output of this code?

Comment: I am using this image as a list view element. The source path for this img element is dynamically bound. So my code will be like `<ItemTemplate >  <img src=<%#Container.DataItem%> />
  </ItemTemplate>` . And the html output I get is `<img src=/Img/sld/H1_DTB_SB_CB.svg />
`

Comment: are you sure the path to the file is correct? also, you should put quotes around the filename, like `<img src='<%#Container.DataItem%>' />`  example:  http://tecfa.unige.ch/guides/svg/ex/html5/html5-with-img-src.html

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the path of the src, since this renders fine with the <embed> and <iframe> elements

Comment: @John I added the quotes too. Still doesn't work. I  don't know why it works without quotes when I use <embed> or <iframe> but doesn't work with <img> no matter what I do

Answer (score 1):

Item #5 on http://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/

1. Using an <img> Tag

SVGs can be added to your web page like any other image:
view plainprint?

```
<img src="image.svg" />
```

The usual width, height, alt and other attributes can be added should you require them.

You’re probably wondering why img isn’t #1 in this list. For security reasons, browsers will disable SVG scripts, linking and other types of interactivity when they’re added to your page with an img tag. In addition, IE9, Chrome and Safari won’t apply stylesheet rules to the SVG if they’re defined in a separate CSS file.

maybe as a workaround you could do something like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Contains(".svg") ? 
            "<object type='image/svg+xml' data='" + Container.DataItem + "'>Your browser does not support SVG</object>" : 
            "<img src='" + Container.DataItem + "' />"
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I have seen this link before. It doesn't help my case much because, I am not using any scripts or linking and I'm not applying any stylesheet to the SVG . I even tried specifying the name of the file directly in the <img> outside of the listview. Still doesn't work

Comment: Could you try with a known working svg? maybe there's an error in your svg file that's causing the browser to not display it.  this one works for me http://tecfa.unige.ch/guides/svg/ex/html5/green-circle.svg

Comment: The green circle is being displayed properly. I wonder why mine is not rendering.

Comment: you'll probably have to show the src of that svg to find the error.

Comment: I don't think it will help. The file is a complex drawing that was drawn with some tool and the final output was converted to svg by the tool. It's a huge file. And I wonder why the <embed> didn't have a problem rendering it

Comment: And one more thing I noticed is that, when I tried right clicking on the image element on the browser and opening it in new tab, the browser simply downloads the file

Comment: That suggests you're not sending a mime-type. The embed has a fallback in the type attribute so that's why that works. Check the page info (right click in Firefox) and look at the Type line.

Answer (score 0):

In your "aspx" page use :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In your code file "aspx.cs" :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\YourFolder\");
                List<String> images = new List<string>(filePaths.Count());
                foreach (string item in filePaths)
                {
                         images.Add(String.Format("~/yourVirtualImgFolder/"+Path.GetFileName(item)));
                }

                RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
                RepeaterImages.DataBind();
}
```

Note that you should create a Virtual Folder "**yourVirtualFolder**" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx#